# How to block mouse input from transparent window with Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I have a main window in a process that is not owned by the program I'm creating. I'm using a `Windows Hook` to inject a DLL into this process for the purpose of adding a child window to this main window.

My end goal was to create a `WS_EX_LAYERED` window that allows me to create an internal colored border but allow the center portion to be transparent and allow mouse clicks through. This part works perfectly.

```
WNDCLASS wndClass = {};
wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc = OverlayProc;
wndClass.hInstance = g_TargetInstance;
wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 255));
wndClass.lpszClassName = "OVERLAY";

RegisterClass(&wndClass);
g_Window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "OVERLAY", nullptr,
    WS_CHILDWINDOW, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right+1, rect.bottom+1, data->hwnd, nullptr, g_TargetInstance, nullptr);

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(g_Window, RGB(0, 255, 255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

ShowWindow(g_Window, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(g_Window);
```

The 2nd part to this is a I wanted to conditionally block all mouse input to the parent window. I couldn't do this with the transparent portion of the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window so I tried creating a 2nd transparent `STATIC` control as a child of the main window but this doesn't block mouse input either.

I'm also sending simulated mouse clicks to the parent window through calls to `PostMessage`, passing `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP`. How could I block all mouse input to the parent window via a transparent window?

Comment: You could set the third arg of SetLayeredWindowAttributes to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: You don't want to use SetWindowsHookEx, do you?

Comment: *"I'm also sending simulated mouse clicks to the parent window through calls to `PostMessage`"* - That's not simulating input. It's faking it. And it's doing [a damn poor job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) at it, too.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure you understand what the word `simulate` means. Simulating input is exactly the same thing as "faking" it. Also, I'm not nor did I say that I was "faking" keyboard input but to be clear, I do have a test function for "faking" keyboard input using `PostMessage` and in my case it works perfectly and reliably so saying it's a "damn poor job" is rather subjective.

Comment: @KonstantinL I am using SetWindowsHookEx and I do want to use that but only for a vehicle to inject my own message handlers and windows into the target process.

Comment: @KonstantinL I've tried setting the 3rd attribute of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to 1 but this causes my window to be 100% transparent and my custom drawn border goes away. I also tried creating a 2nd layered window with this argument and unfortunately it did not stop mouse input.

Comment: Which portion of the link I posted do you find *"subjective"*? It clearly explains, why faking input using `PostMessage` will inevitably fail. It bypasses standard input processing, and consequently you cannot filter such fake input (which requires input to be processed). `SendInput` was invented to properly simulate input. All of that is explained in the link I posted. Did you not read it?

Comment: @IInspectable `SendInput` would not work in my particular circumstance and I find it subjective because it won't always fail in every situation. In my particular situation it will not fail and works perfectly due to the way the target application is processing the messages, but I digress, your comment had nothing to do with my question whatsoever. Maybe subjective is the incorrect term in this case, it's more of a matter of it being irrelevant for my situation.

Comment: *"I'm also sending simulated mouse clicks to the parent window through calls to `PostMessage`, passing `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP`. How could I block all mouse input to the parent window via a transparent window?"* - You can't. That simple. It's fake, not simulated. It doesn't get processed, like simulated input. Use the proper tool and your problems will go away. Added bonus: This **does** *"work perfectly"*, unlike your hack. This **is** part of the question you asked, no?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't understand your suggestions at all. You suggest using `SendInput`? SendInput will not work in my situation so I need to find a different way. If a transparent window will not work, I need to find a different way. I have found a solution and albeit a hack, it works and I'm afraid in this situation there is no "proper" non-hacky way to do it. I also have no idea what you mean by "fake" versus "simulated", there really is no point to either, regardless if it's "fake" or "simulated" the end result is the same. Furthermore, there was no mention of keyboard input at all.

Comment: The end result is different. I have explained, why, and so did the link I offered. If that doesn't sink in with you, there's likely a fundamental lack of understanding, how input works in Windows. You need to catch up on that, if you wish to produce reliable solutions.

Comment: @IInspectable Your information was for keyboard input only `You can’t simulate **keyboard** input with PostMessage` and does not pertain to mouse input at all. This thread is ended, it is getting too long. Please contact me directly if you wish to continue arguing a moot point.

Comment: This is not about you. Stack Overflow is for everyone, and even if you don't care, someone else might: The same issues apply to mouse input (you'd know this, if you understood input): The fake input does not get processed, leaving the input system in an inconsistent state. Depending on the API you are using, you will get contradicting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is not possible to do with a simple transparent window drawn over sibling controls. What I ended up doing was using `SetWindowHookEx` to add a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook into the process from which I use to replace the main window's WndProc function and intercept mouse messages. I tag my simulated mouse messages with a specific value in the `wParam` argument so the proc will now it was simulated and removes that value, passing it along to the parent window.

If it does not detect my "tag" value in the click message, it will swallow the mouse message and not pass it along to the original WndProc function.

**Injected WndProc replacement**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            wParam -= 11141008;
            if (wParam != MK_LBUTTON && !g_Paused)
                return 0;
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            wParam -= 11141008;
            if (wParam != 0 && !g_Paused)
                return 0;
            break;

        case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            if (!g_Paused)
                return 0;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**Snippet from Windows Hook function**

```
//...
switch (data->message)
{
    case (WM_USER + 1):
    {
        g_Paused = FALSE;
        //...
        SetWindowSubclass(data->hwnd, WndProc, 1, 0);
        break;
    }

    case (WM_USER + 2):
    {
        RemoveWindowSubclass(data->hwnd, WndProc, 1);
        //...
        break;
    }
}
//...
```

The code inside the window hook function is used to subclass the main process window and inject my own WndProc function which in turn processes mouse input the way I want.

This is the code used to "simulate" mouse clicks without physically clicking in the window. Note the added value to `wParam` to identify this click as simulated and not generated by the user.

```
void Window::LeftClick(DWORD x, DWORD y, DWORD delayMillis)
{
    LPARAM lparam = MAKELPARAM(x, y);

    lock_guard<mutex> lock(this->m_ClickMutex);

    PostMessage(this->m_Window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 11141008 + MK_LBUTTON, lparam);
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delayMillis));
    PostMessage(this->m_Window, WM_LBUTTONUP, 11141008, lparam);
}
```

Also, just for the person in the comments who was ridiculing my choice of the word `simulated` and the added criticism for using `PostMessage` to simulate keyboard input, here is my keyboard input test method which (for my purposes) works flawlessly and very reliably

```
void GameWindow::KeyPress(UINT vkCode) const
{
    UINT scanCode = MapVirtualKey(vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    LPARAM lparam1 = MAKELPARAM(1, scanCode);
    LPARAM lparam2 = MAKELPARAM(1, 0xC000 | scanCode);

    PostMessage(this->m_Window, WM_KEYDOWN, vkCode, lparam1);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(25));
    PostMessage(this->m_Window, WM_KEYUP, vkCode, lparam2);
}
```

Comment: The person wasn't *"ridiculing [your] choice of the work `simulated`"*. He was explaining, that your input **isn't** being simulated at all, but faked. That person also provided a link with substantial information, what is wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: @IInspectable You provided information about keyboard input only, which is NOT what I asked for at all.

Comment: Similar issues apply to mouse input. The underlying problem is the same: Your faked input does not get **processed**.